# default routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I have following route configuration,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ProductRoute",
                url: "{productName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Now if i give some thing like this, **localhost:56789/prd1/Home/Index**

The first routing is working.

However if i directly access **localhost:56789/Home/Index** or any other controller action, like **localhost:56789/Account/Login** the routing is not working.

1. Is it because I have a {productName} defined?
2. For testing purpose how can I add few products like prd1, prd2 along with routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are matched against the request in the order they are defined. When a route matching the request is found, no further routes are considered. Thus, you need to list your routes in order of decreasing specificity.

However, your first route matches *more* requests than your second route, i.e. it is *less* specific than the second route:

When ASP.NET MVC tries to match the request for `Home/Index` to your routes, it will match the first route because it will consider `Home` to be the `productName`, it will consider `Index` to be the `controller` name and the rest of the parameters are not required.

You need to reorder your routes or make the first route more specific. This could be done by putting constraints on the `productName` parameter.

**UPDATE**

Without knowing anything about your products and their names, it is impossible for me to suggest an appropriate constraint. Maybe you could use a numeric SKU and have a constraint like

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProductRoute",
            url: "{productName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { productName = @"\d+" }
            );
```

forcing `productName` to be numeric.

Alternatively, you could change the url to

```
"products/{productName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

For more on constraints see [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) or use Google.

Comment: Could you please suggest how can I go about that? Adding constraints?

Answer (score 1):

For route configuration

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ProductRoute",
           url: "{productName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { productName = 'put your method name to get productName over here', controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },

           namespaces: new string[] { "your namespace of controller" });


 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```